# Eclipse cannot find the declaration of JavaEE 10 root elements in deployment descriptors

Tags: eclipse, jpa

In Eclipse I created a new maven project for a Java Web Application.
Adding the corresponding deployment descriptors for Servlet, Faces, Persistance, etc.
I am getting exceptions for the root element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence 
    xmlns="http://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="project"
    version="3.1">
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Also for the faces-config deployment descriptor the root element is not found:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_4_0.xsd"
    version="4.0">

</faces-config>
```

- Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'
- Cannot find the declaration of element 'faces-config'
- Downloading external resources is disabled.

[image]

Seems like Eclipse does not download the xsd and so cannot validate the correct xml root.

How to enabled Eclipse to correctly download and validate? Honour all xml schema locations is enabled.

Thanks for ideas!

Comment: Which release of Eclipse is this?

Comment: @nitind - Version: 2023-09 (4.29.0)
Build id: 20230907-1323

Answer (score 0):

Do the same as Eclipse.

Try to download the https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_1.xsd.

You'll notice that it returns 404. Eclipse also faces this problem and can't do any magic.

Go to the parent location https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence to find available XSDs.

You'll notice that there's indeed no such XSD.

Use https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_3_0.xsd instead, it's compatible with 3.1.

It's indeed mind-blowingly unintuitive, [but it is what it is](https://github.com/jakartaee/persistence/issues/372).

Comment: Thanks Bauke, that was one of the issues (copied from you book, btw). I corrected the URL but the issue is still there. I added the faces-config descriptor. Eclipse has the same issue here. Cannot find the root element.
I wonder where the 'Downloading external resources is disabled' error is coming from I guess that is the issue. Thx

Comment: That book was written long before Jakarta EE 10 was officially released (publisher pressure :/ I'm personally not entirely happy with the book because it was as being second revision not even proofread, so a bunch of mistakes slipped through). The skip of the Persistence 3.1 XSD was completely unexpected.

Comment: The 'Downloading external resources is disabled' "error" is coming from a Language Server, most likely Lemminx.

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me today, with the maven project schema xsd, which was available online. After like 5 minutes of poking around I've hovered my mouse in the opened xml file over the schema URL and a tooltip appeared with the option to 'force download' the file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make @BalusC answer to work in regards of the "Eclipse Downloading external resources is disabled" problem. It helps to enable automatic downloads for resources in XML.**Go to:**

Window->Preferences->XML(Wild Web Developer) and enable Download external resources like referenced DTD,XSD

--- I can not make comments so I am adding this as extension of the answer from BalusC